# GUI calculations are off after a few changes in options

Tags: java, swing, combobox, awt, actionlistener

I am having a bit of trouble with an issue. I don't fully understand what the problem is, but I keep getting bizarre values when I try and calculate it. It works as I change the combobox values a few times. But then it starts spitting out unfeasible numbers. The error lies somewhere in here:

```
private void updateTripDurationText()
{

    String speed = (String)avgspeedBox.getSelectedItem();
    String dist = (String)distanceText.getText();
    double d = Double.parseDouble(dist);
    double s = Double.parseDouble(speed);
    double durationT = d/s;
    String durationTime = String.format("%.1f",(Double.valueOf(durationT)));
    durationText.setText(durationTime);

 }



private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener
 {


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

          setCities(destinationBox.getSelectedIndex(),originBox.getSelectedIndex());
     updateDistanceText();
        updateTripDurationText();   

   }

 }

//This is the actionlistender that triggers our actions when the radio buttons are used. Miles is selected  by default however.
private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {

   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {   

    if (event.getSource() == kilometersRadioButton)
     {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (kilometers):");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speeg (kph): ");
            setKm(true);


     }
     else if (event.getSource() == milesRadioButton)
     {
            distanceLabel.setText("Distance (miles): ");
            avgspeedLabel.setText("Avg. Speeg (mph): ");
            setKm(false);

     }
        updateDistanceText();
        updateTripDurationText();

    }

 }

public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  new TripCalculator();
 }
}
```

The problem is exclusively with updateTripDuration. But I cannot find what is causing it. For some more detail. When this calculates the distance between two locations then takes the average speed and divides the distance by it. However, with this setup it only works one or two changes then it is off and remains off.

Comment: I think that nobody from this description and code, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: back to your previous question (answer are based on quite poor question), the same in this question too, add Integer or Double value to ComboBoxModel